# Check if substring is in string

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a list

```
test = ["a","bb","ph","phi","phi_ph"]
```

where a member of `test` can either contain the string `ph`, the string `phi`, a combination of these two, or none of them. How can I filter this list to retain only the elements containing `ph` such that:

```
test_filtered = ["ph","phi_ph"]
```

when e.g.

```
[x for x in test if 'ph' in x]
```

returns

```
>> ["ph","phi","phi_ph"]
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the `test_filtered` list?

Comment: `[x for x in test if "ph" in x and x != "phi"]`?

Comment: `[x for x in test if 'ph' in x and x.endswith('ph')]` ?

Comment: how this value `"phi_ph_phi"` should be treated?

Comment: @rassar The reasoning is that I'm interested only in the variables containing `ph`, which I want to use for something different than the `phi`. That however includes strings containing both `ph` and `phi`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `"phi_ph_phi"` is accepted.

Comment: @sphericalcowboy That wouldn't cover e.g. `"phi_abc"`, which I don't want in my filtered list.

Comment: @Demosthene `phi` contains `ph` as a substring so it is not clear what you want.

Comment: @Goyo The idea is that if my strings contain at least `ph` then they contain either `ph` or `phi`. I want only strings that do not contain `phi` as the only `ph`-substring.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `re.compile()` and `re.search()` functions:

```
import re

test = ["a","bb","ph","phi","phi_ph", "phi_abc", "ph_a"]
search_str = 'ph'

pattern = re.compile(r'(^|[^a-z0-9])'+ search_str + '([^a-z0-9]|$)')
result = [i for i in test if re.search(pattern, i)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['ph', 'phi_ph', 'ph_a']
```

---

`(^|[^a-z0-9])` - alternation group, ensures that the search string(i.e. `ph`) should occur at the start of the string or preceded by non-alphanumeric character

`([^a-z0-9]|$)` - alternation group, ensures that the search string(i.e. `ph`) should occur at the end of the string or followed by non-alphanumeric character

Comment: @JurajBezručka, I've made an edit before you added your comment(time difference). See my update

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed. No other objections :)

Comment: @JurajBezručka, that's ok

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of it:

```
test = ["a","bb","ph","phi","phi_ph"]

result = [y for y in test for x in y.split('_') if x == "ph"]
```

This way you only include `"ph"` and you don't need to exclude anything.

Comment: Better would be `[y for y in test if 'ph' in y.split('_')]`. As it is, if `"ph_ph"` was in your starting list, your result would include it twice.

Comment: It might be that I'm given a list where `ph` isn't neatly separated by an underscore...

Comment: Sure, yours is a simpler version :)

Comment: @Demosthenewe can only answer questions relative to the data provided, if you provide more possible list variables we would be glad to give you updated answers

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the following list comprehension does the job:

```
test_filtered = [x for x in test if ('ph' in x and x.count('ph')!=x.count('phi'))]
>> ['ph', 'phi_ph']
```

Comment: I was about to recommend using `count()` as well. This should cover all cases you mentioned.

Comment: Works with: `test = ["a", "bb", "phx", "phi", "phi_ph", "abc_ph_phi", "abc_phi_phi", "phiph", "phiphi", "phiphiph"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [26]: new_filter=[ x.split('_')[0] for x in test_filtered]+test_filtered
In [27]: [x for x in test if x in new_filter]
Out[27]: ['ph', 'phi', 'phi_ph']
```